# How to use a custom setter method from prepareforsegueue

Tags: ios, objective-c

Scenario consists of two VC's.  VC1 has a push segue to VC2.  VC2 has a public property in the h file called array.  VC2 has a custom setter defined for array.  As follows:

VC1 .m file

```
@implementation PBVViewController

-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {


NSMutableArray *feeder = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"one", @"two", @"three", nil];

[(PBVVC2 *)segue.destinationViewController setArray:feeder] ;

}

@end
```

vc2 .h file

```
@interface PBVVC2 : UIViewController

@property (copy, nonatomic) NSMutableArray *array;

-(void)setArray:(NSMutableArray *)array;

@end
```

VC2 . m file

```
@implementation PBVVC2

-(void)setArray:(NSMutableArray *)array{

if (_array == nil){

    _array = array;
}

else {
    //do some stuff here before setting _array
}
}
@end
```

The problem is in the custom setter in VC2 .m file, _array is ALWAYS nil.  I expect _array to be nil the first time the prepareforsegue method runs and VC2 is shown.  However, I expected that the second time I navigate to VC2 that _array should be set from last time and that I can check what it is set to....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use storyboards, iOS creates a new instance of `VC2` every time the segue is triggered. The only way to change it that I know is to perform push controllers manually, but it's not really convinient. 
You could pass the necessary data from `VC2` back to `VC1` (or to a DataController of some sort), and then if it's not nil, set it again in `prepareForSegue`.

Comment: Thanks.  What was throwing me is that VC2 has a variable defined inside the implementation like simple int = 5;  I was seeing that variable stay the same value each time.  I now understand, that int variable is like a static variable and shared across all instances of the class.  So even though the segue is creating a new instance, the int variable is staying the same value while the "instance" variable  _array is being reset.

Comment: Yes. It is probably defined outside the function? If so, then it is not an instance variable, but a usual C global variable. You are right, one copy of it is shared among all class instances. If you need an instance variable, you can define it inside the `@interface` block.